Excel, generate a list of names depending on row and column values of another sheet
I have a similar excel sheet which has dates in Column A and Names in the Row 1. Each name has a value per day.



Date
Alice
Bob
Charl
Dan




01/01/24
E
L
E
E


02/01/24
E
L
L
A



I need another sheet that lists dates in the first column, value in second column and then that row list all names with corresponding values in the first sheet. Something like:



Date
Value
Name1
Name2
Name3




01/01/24
E
Alice
Charl
Dan


01/01/24
L
Bob




01/01/24
A





02/01/24
E
Alice




02/01/24
L
Bob
Charl



02/01/24
A
Dan





I'm using Microsoft excel 365
How can this be achieved? I can't find a excel formula that returns multiple values for a corresponding row. I've been going in circles for ages so any help is greatly appreciated.
Edit: I think Index and Aggregate get close to it, as shown here
https://www.xelplus.com/return-multiple-match-values-in-excel/
but I can't quit figure it out.

Look into Power Query unpivot.

Using Power Query it will be lot easier than using an Excel Formula:



Convert the ranges into Structured References aka Tables and name it as Table1`
Open a blank query from Data Tab --> Get Data --> From Other Sources --> Blank Query
From Home Tab --> Click on Advanced Editor --> delete anything what you see and paste the following:


let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    DataType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Alice", type text}, {"Bob", type text}, {"Charl", type text}, {"Dan", type text}}),
    UnpivotOtherCols = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(DataType, {"Date"}, "Name", "Value"),
    GroupBy = Table.Group(UnpivotOtherCols, {"Date", "Value"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}, {"All", each _, type table [Date=nullable date, Attribute=text, Value=text]}}),
    ExtractNames = Table.AddColumn(GroupBy, "Name", each [All][Name]),
    Expanded = Table.TransformColumns(ExtractNames, {"Name", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "|"), type text}),
    SplitByDelim = Table.SplitColumn(Expanded, "Name", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Name.1", "Name.2", "Name.3"}),
    RemovedCols = Table.RemoveColumns(SplitByDelim,{"Count", "All"})
in
    RemovedCols



Now, below one can find a Done button, click on it.
From File --> Click on Close & Load or Close & Load To import data to Excel to get the desired output.
Now, with every addition of new data, just refresh the imported table to get the updated results.


Using Excel Formulas:


• MAKEARRAY():
=LET(
     _Data, Table1[#All],
     _Names, DROP(TAKE(_Data,1),,1),
     _Vals, UNIQUE(TOCOL(DROP(_Data,1,1))),
     _Date, DROP(TAKE(_Data,,1),1),
     _DateExpanded, TOCOL(IFNA(EXPAND(_Date,,ROWS(_Vals)),_Date)),
     _ValsExpanded, TOCOL(IFNA(EXPAND(_Vals,,ROWS(_Date)),_Vals),,1),
     _DataBody, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(G2:G7),ROWS(_Vals),LAMBDA(r,c,
            INDEX(TOROW(IFS((INDEX(_DateExpanded,r)=_Date)*
            (INDEX(_ValsExpanded,r)=DROP(_Data,1,1)),_Names),2),c))),
     _Output, IFERROR(HSTACK(_DateExpanded,_ValsExpanded, _DataBody),""),
 VSTACK(HSTACK("Date","Value","Name"&SEQUENCE(,ROWS(_Vals))),_Output))


• REDUCE():
=LET(
     _Data, Table1[#All],
     _Vals, UNIQUE(TOCOL(DROP(_Data,1,1),3)),
     _Output, IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(_Data)-1),LAMBDA(a,b,
          VSTACK(a, DROP(REDUCE("",_Vals,LAMBDA(c,d,
          LET(e, CHOOSEROWS(DROP(_Data,1),b), f, TAKE(e,,1),
          VSTACK(c,HSTACK(f,d,IFERROR(FILTER(DROP(TAKE(_Data,1),,1),DROP(e,,1)=d),"")))))),1)))),1),""),
      VSTACK(HSTACK(A2,"Value","Name"&SEQUENCE(,ROWS(_Vals))),_Output))



That's excellent, thanks for explaining it clear steps. I do have to convince (and trust) someone to click refresh but it works very well.

@user25652804 what you have is not a question for Excel Formulas, it is a question for Power Query which works very well, in such conditions. and way simpler that formulas. Stacking and unpivoting using formulas with larger data may get slower based on various conditions. Using PQ is apt here.

Power Query is better, but using formula for fun:
To view the result of each step, change final variable (unpivotted).
=LAMBDA(names, dates, values,
    LET(
        uniq_values, UNIQUE(TOCOL(values)),
        values_for_date, LAMBDA(date_,
            INDEX(values, XMATCH(date_, dates), )
        ),
        names_for_date_values, LAMBDA(date_, values,
            DROP(
                REDUCE(
                    "",
                    values,
                    LAMBDA(acc, value,
                        VSTACK(
                            acc,
                            FILTER(
                                names,
                                values_for_date(date_) = value,
                                ""
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                1
            )
        ),
        format_date, LAMBDA(date_, TEXT(date_, "mm/dd/yyyy")),
        date_value_names, DROP(
            REDUCE(
                "",
                dates,
                LAMBDA(acc, date_,
                    VSTACK(
                        acc,
                        HSTACK(
                            EXPAND(
                                format_date(date_),
                                ROWS(uniq_values),
                                ,
                                format_date(date_)
                            ),
                            uniq_values,
                            names_for_date_values(
                                date_,
                                uniq_values
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            1
        ),
        header, HSTACK(
            "Date",
            "Value",
            "Name" & TOROW(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(date_value_names) - 2))
        ),
        unpivotted, VSTACK(header, IFNA(date_value_names, "")),
        unpivotted
    )
)(B1:E1, A2:A3, B2:E3)



Transform Data: Unpivot
=LET(list,A1:E3,rlr_title,"Value",vals_title,"Name",
    shv,DROP(TAKE(list,1),,1),
    sd,DROP(list,1),
    sdr,ROWS(sd),
    sr,TAKE(sd,,1),
    sv,DROP(sd,,1),
    vu,UNIQUE(TOCOL(sv)),
    vur,ROWS(vu),
    vus,SEQUENCE(vur),
    drl,HSTACK(TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,vur),sr)),
        TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,sdr),vu),,1)),
    dv,IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(sdr),LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
        svr,CHOOSEROWS(sv,r),
        VSTACK(rr,DROP(REDUCE("",vus,LAMBDA(cc,c,
            VSTACK(cc,FILTER(shv,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(svr,
            CHOOSEROWS(vu,c))),"")))),1))))),1),""),
    dh,HSTACK(TAKE(list,1,1),rlr_title,vals_title&SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(dv))),
    r,VSTACK(dh,HSTACK(drl,dv)),
    r)


